# Como criar variáveis dinâmicas no javascript dentro de um loop

Tags: javascript

tenho o seguinte código e queria dar uma melhorada nele.

```
 if(id == 1)
        if(myWindow1){
        myWindow1.form_1.submit();
        myWindow1 = "";

    }
    if(id == 2)
        if(myWindow2){
            myWindow2.form_2.submit();
            myWindow2 = "";
        }

    if(id == 3)
        if(myWindow3){        
            myWindow3.form_3.submit();
            myWindow3 = "";
        }
    if(id == 4)
        if(myWindow4){            
            myWindow4.form_4.submit();
            myWindow4 = "";
        }
    if(id == 5)
        if(myWindow5){
            myWindow5.form_5.submit();
            myWindow5  = "";
        }
```

onde myWindow ... e um popup que pode ter sido criado. Se eu sei a quantidade de popup que foram criadas( e sei ) poderia fazer mais ou menos dessa forma (como faço em PHP)

```
while($contador < $qtdAlgo){
 $nomeVariavel = ${"myWindow". $contador}
 $contador++;
}
```

Assim iria pegar todas variaveis que ja existem e conseguiria fazer algo com elas... Existem uma forma para eu manter meu código la em cima 
{ myWindow1.form_1.submit() } ?

Obs. o form_1 também teria que ser concatenado.

ou seja mais ou menos assim

myWindow {contador} .form_ {contador}.submit();

Comment: Podes fazer myWindow[contador]

Comment: Seria interessante ver como são criados os popups.

Answer (score 1):

```
for(var i=0; i < qtdeForms; i++) { 
    var formCount = i + 1;
    if ( 'myWindow' + formCount in window) {
         window['myWindow' + formCount]['form_' + formCount].submit();
    }
}
```

Isto pode resolver o teu problema, mas aconselho você a trocar de lógica, pois desta forma o seu código tende a piorar cada vez mais.

Answer (score 1):

Porque vc nao coloca todos os ids em um array, depois vc faz um loop, e depois dentro do loop vc nao faz o que precisa com os ID?

```
// Array inicial
var IDformularios = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

var validaFormularios = function (formularios) {
  var forms = window.IDformularios || []
    if (!forms.length) {
        return new Error('Nao tem formularios')
    } else {
    // LOOP
        forms.forEach(function(form) {
      var nome = 'form'+form
      // EXECUTA LOGICA
          executaLogicaNoFormulario(form)
      // OU CRIA SUA VARIAVEL AQUI
      criaVariavelDinamica(nome)
        })

    }
}

var executaLogicaNoFormulario = function (formulario) {
    if (!formulario) {
        return new Error('Nenhum formulario')
    } else {
        // Logica para o formulario
        console.log('[executaLogicaNoFormulario]: executaLogicaNoFormulario: ', formulario)
    }
}

var novoPopUp = function (nome, id, blababla) {
    if (!nome && !id) return // sem nome e sem ID
    var forms = window.IDformularios || []
    forms.push(id)
    window.open(/* seus popups ... */)
}

var criaVariavelDinamica = function ( nome ) {
  if( window[nome] == null ){
    console.log('nova variavel adicionada:', 'window.'+nome);
    window[nome] = ''
  } else {
    console.log('Variavel ja existe: ', 'window.'+nome);
  }
}

validaFormularios(IDformularios)
```